# Java Android Studio - Recuperar ip do dispositivo

Tags: java, android

Bom dia, amigos! Alguém sabe como que eu posso recuperar o ip de um dispositivo android? Consegui alguns códigos, mas apenas para recuperar o ip do wifi. Preciso desse ip, pois estou trabalhando em um aplicativo de anúncios, e para não ficar contando vários clicks para o anunciante, eu teria que bloquear esse ip temporariamente. Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um Webservice como AWS

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

URL meuIP = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(meuIP.openStream()));

String ip = in.readLine(); //você terá seu IP como uma String
System.out.println(ip);
```